# How to programmatically access the main interface

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios8

I've been using the following code untill now to get the storyboard:

```
NSString * storyboardName = @"myStoryboard";
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
```

However, I now have a project with multiple targets, each with their own storyboard. This code no longer works, because the name of these storyboards is different for all targets. Is there a way to get the storyboard that is set as "main interface" in my target, without knowing the name of the storyboard at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your UIViewControllers
Use

```
Storyboard *storyboard =self.storyboard;
```

instead of

```
Storyboard *storyboard =[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
```

Comment: I'm calling this code from a class that is not a UIViewController, can it still be done?.

Comment: Nevermind I got it, I'm passing the view controller that calls this as parameter to the function and it works :) thanks.